# Print all text of text field in Flash AS 3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Hello everyone,
                I am Working on Flash as 3 with air .i have a text field  of size 200*200 which contain some large   this text can seen  by scrolling and i want to print all the text . i have a sprite and its child is text field which contain that text  ,i have print job to print the   text. but it print only one page.

How can i print all content ....

Comment: Can you post some code regarding how you're creating the print job?

Comment: TextField is added to sprite function selectedPrintCommand(event:Event):void
  {
   if(textfield.text!="")
   {
    try
    {
     myPrintJob=new PrintJob();
     myPrintJob.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE,onDeactivate);
     myPrintJob.start();
     myPrintJob.addPage(sprite); /// sprite.addchild(textField); textfield is add to sprite
     myPrintJob.send();
    } 
    catch(error:Error) 
    {
     trace("print job cancle");
    }
    removeChild(sprite);
   }
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the text field after you add it to the sprite but before you print it. So you can make the height bigger to show all the text. If its large amount of text you might think about creating a print version of the text field where you can copy the text from the originating text field an format it to be even more printable i.e. screen display and print versions of text can often need to be different.

Comment: Dave: i have re sized myTextField but printJob print only 1 page...not all text of  mytextfield

Comment: Flash printing really just prints the movie clip or clips you send to print job. So, if you want your text to appear on multiple pages, you need chop up your text and place it in separate movie clips. You'll have to measure how many lines can appear on a page, size your text field to have margins,etc. That's why I said you might want to have a print view of your text too.